# Regular Expression For String(Fix Value )+ Opreator + integer

Tags: c#, regex

Hi i want to create one Custom Regular expression in which value first part of string must be fix upto string index[10] i.e @SystemDate after that there must be one opreator either + or - after that two digit of integer value i tried but not getting it please go through  below code and suggest me changes

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(_SelectedSystem, "@SystemDate{1}[+/-]$ {2}[0-9]{2}$"))
                        {
                            global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
                        }
```

Comment: You might want to look up what `$` means in a regular expression for starters. And give some examples in your question of what you want to match and what you *don't* want to match.

Comment: Your explanation makes no sense at all. Perhaps if you would give a set of example inputs and explain what you expect to happen for each of the inputs, that would make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"(^@SystemDate$)|^@SystemDate[+|-]{1}\d+$"

Comment: This is not a good regex as [it also allows `|` after `SystemDate`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5e%40SystemDate%24)%7c%5e%40SystemDate%5b%2b%7c-%5d%7b1%7d%5cd%2b%24&i=%40SystemDate%7c234&o=m). You need `@"^@SystemDate(?:[+-]\d+)?$"`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
@SystemDate[+-]\d{2}$
```

Breaking it down you match:

```
@SystemDate     literally
[+-]            match + or -
\d{2}           match exactly 2 digits
$               end of string
```

See: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL6vD9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `|` symbol in the character class, each symbol is treated as a single character inside it.

You need

```
@"^@SystemDate(?:[+-]\d+)?$"
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%40SystemDate(%3F%3A%5B%2B-%5D%5Cd%2B)%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=%40SystemDate%0D%0A%40SystemDate-234%0D%0A%40SystemDate%2B234&o=m)

The `(?:[+-]\d+)?` is an optional non-capturing group, it can be present or not. `[+-]` matches exactly 1 `+` or `-`.